# LDAP URL example: is it possible / correct to use only the domain without the hostname?

Tags: ldap, cluster, url, networking

We have an application which connects to an Active Directory (MS) using LDAP protocol.

We give usually the following parameters:

```
 ldapUrl        = ldap://myserver.mydomain.ext:389
 ldapBaseDn     = OU=DPT,DC=mydomain,DC=org
 ldapBindDn     = CN=ldapuser,OU=Service Account,DC=mydomain,DC=org
 ldapBindPwd    = thepassword
```

Some people in our organisation says that the hostname (myserver) is not mandatory anymore and the url could be defined like this:

```
 ldapUrl        = ldap://mydomain.ext/
```

... and the domain controller will find automatically find which LDAP (AD) server to use (it is in a clustered environment)

I know the port is not mandatory as the 389 is the default port for LDAP protocol, but I never heard that the server is optional as well.

Can somebody confirm it is correct or not and if it is, point me to an article (because yes, I tried to google it, but did not find anything useful).

I guess if that notation is supported it is not always the case for all (LDAP) clients and perhaps it is only a Microsoft shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it might be true for AD (I don't know if it is or not), this is not certainly not correct in a general sense for LDAP. I guess AD will add some SRV records into the DNS allowing this, but there is no guarantee a client actually reads them when trying to connect to an LDAP server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in fact you point me to the right place by mentionning DNS. In fact by doing a nslookup mydomain.org I can see a list of all the IP's (which are the DC/AD).